# Shared memory permissions denied error with apache httpd module

Tags: c++, apache

Why am I getting a permission denied error when opening shared memory (created by a non-root user) with an apache c++ module, even though I'm starting apache httpd as root?

Comment: Show a [mcve], then *maybe* we'll have a chance to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache modules are typically run as an `apache` non-root user.  As such, they do not have the same permissions that root has.  Therefore, you need to chmod your shared memory file such that the `apache` non-root user can access it -- perhaps by granting "others" read/write access, e.g.,

```
chmod go+rw /dev/shm/your_shm_file
```